# How to queue a completion port action (I/O bound function) to CLR ThreadPool

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, io, threadpool

I have an external library that does long running I/O. I wish to create a multithreaded application that will use ThreadPool to limit simultaneous number of threads *and* I wish to add threads handing these external calls as completion port thread (I/O threads) rather than worker threads (so that limit for compute bound threads) is intact.

I have a code sample, that omits external library but shows what I've tried already.

Does anyone know how to do that? Or is it even possible. Thank you

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace ThreadPoolTest
{
    class MainApp
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10, 10);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoWork); //doesn't work - a compute-bound thread 

            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10, 10);

             //doesn't work - still a compute-bound thread 
            ((Action<object>)DoWork).BeginInvoke(null, Callback, null);

            Console.Read();
        }

        static void DoWork(object o)
        {
            ShowAvailableThreads();
            //call to external library - that does a long I/O operation
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        static void Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            ShowAvailableThreads();
        }

        static void ShowAvailableThreads()
        {
            int workerThreads, completionPortThreads;

            ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out workerThreads,
               out completionPortThreads);
            Console.WriteLine("WorkerThreads: {0}," +
               " CompletionPortThreads: {1}",
               workerThreads, completionPortThreads);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might have to drop down to unmanaged code, see e.g. http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/IOCP-Thread-Pooling-in-C-sharp-Part-II/

Comment: my first guess too - looking at the link you've shared - it doen't look too difficult either. But, I'll wait some more for easier solution if any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can queue work for the I/O threads as described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150625032527/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericeil/archive/2008/06/20/windows-i-o-threads-vs-managed-i-o-threads.aspx).

> The managed QueueUserWorkItem queues
> work to the "worker threads" only.
> UnsafeQueueNativeOverlapped queues to
> the I/O threads, as do completions for
> asynchronous I/O performed on kernel
> objects that have been bound to the
> ThreadPool via BindHandle.